# React native slider not updating progress on state update

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm using react native version **0.61.5** and react version **16.8.3** with react native gifted chat version **0.9.11** to build a small chat app. I want to send audio messages. So I use **react-native-audio-recorder-player** library to record audio and play it. So far audio recording and playing is a success. Now I want to play the audio track progress when user play the audio. I used **react-native-community/react-native-slider** to display a seekbar. This is how the audio message look like

[image]

When user press the play button I want to show the audio track progress on this slider. So far this is how I did it.

Gifted Chat component

```
render() {
  return (
    <GiftedChat
      messages={this.state.messages}
      onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
      scrollToBottom={true}
      renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
      renderComposer={this.renderComposer}
      renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
        name:'You'
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

renderBubble component

```
renderBubble = (props) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <View style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <Button iconLeft transparent onPress={this.onStartPlay}>
            <Icon name='ios-play' />
        </Button>
        <Slider
          style={{width: 150, height: 40}}
          minimumValue={0.0000}
          maximumValue={1.0000}
          value={this.state.audioProgress}
          minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
          maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        />
      </View>
      <Bubble {...props}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

onStartPlay function

```
onStartPlay = async () => {
  console.log('onStartPlay');
  const msg = await audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer('sdcard/test_recording.aac');
  console.log(msg);
  audioRecorderPlayer.addPlayBackListener((e) => {
    if (e.current_position === e.duration) {
      console.log('finished');
      audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
    }
    this.setState({
      currentPositionSec: e.current_position,
      currentDurationSec: e.duration,
      playTime: audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position)),
      duration: audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.duration)),
    });

    let currentProgress = Math.max(0,  e.current_position) /  e.duration;
    console.log('currentProgress',parseFloat(currentProgress).toFixed(4));
    this.setState({ audioProgress: parseFloat(currentProgress).toFixed(4) });
  });
};
```

and I can see in the console current progress is getting updated in the `audioProgress` state. And I'm setting the value of the `Slider` via the `audioProgress` but the position of the seek bar is not getting updated. I'm testing this on Nexus android emulator.

Comment: Hy what you do to move the slider while playing audio? If your issued is solved then could you answer it?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to add the onValueChange to the Slider.
Try adding either:

```
<Slider
          style={{width: 150, height: 40}}
          minimumValue={0.0000}
          maximumValue={1.0000}
          value={this.state.audioProgress}
          onValueChange = {this.state.audioProgress.bind(this)} <===
          minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
          maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        />
```

or

```
<Slider
          style={{width: 150, height: 40}}
          minimumValue={0.0000}
          maximumValue={1.0000}
          value={this.state.audioProgress}
          onValueChange = {this.state.audioProgress} <===
          minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
          maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        />
```

Let me know if it works!